# Memory rises a little after each savepoint ends

Tags: apache-flink

Due to the huge amount of data, my task is to do a savepoint operation every hour. According to the monitoring, the memory will rise a little after every savepoint is done.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YEdq.png)

Although the subsequent memory will decrease, with each savepoint, the memory actually increases

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to think that the overall gradual rise in memory usage is due to these periodic savepoints. It's common for Flink applications to use more memory over time -- especially with the heap-based state backend. Perhaps your keyspace is growing, for example, and so you are keeping more timers and/or state.

(Why the frequent savepoints? Is checkpointing disabled?)

Answer (score 0):

It is something about how JVM memory architecture works. Garbage collection is cleaning short lived objects but promotes most used objects into survivor & old-gen space.

Those increases usually cause by objects left behind, you can not expect all objects will be cleaned immediately in JVM world, may not be cleaned until a major GC.

Changing your JVM GC type to G1GC by enabling `-XX:+UseG1GC` flag could optimize memory usage, but could increase CPU usage a little.

Flink is suitable for G1GC since it process realtime flow like webservices. In other bigdata tools you can prefer standard concurrent mark and swept ( `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` ). JVM uses Parallel GC by default until java-9.

You need to optimize JVM parameters for each application for their usage pattern.